# Difference between "of" and "in"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, prepositions

As a native speaker it's embarrassing for me to not know the difference between "of" and "in", in certain contexts. I'm currently in school right now and sometimes  there are certain phrases which I see on the board which I have no clue of. Can someone give me a good explanation of the differences between "of" and "in" and their general rules?

Comment: That is an extremely general question and will be hard to answer. You mention that it is only in certain contexts that you have difficulty but you do not tell us what they are which makes it even harder.

Comment: Lots of preposition choices are effectively arbitrary, and very often there isn't really *any* particular "meaning" to the particular preposition used in any given instance. And sometimes more than one preposition can be used with *exactly* the same meaning. Hence *It looks like the voters **of / in** London have re-elected Sadiq Khan as mayor.* But to the extent you *can* distinguish between them, ***in*** usually effectively reflects (literal or metaphoric) ***container*** references, where ***of*** might mean "comes from", or simply "associated with".